# What is the right way to use angularjs's data binding in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I didn't find anything about how to accomplish this, so I'm here to asking it.
I have this

```
  if document.documentElement.clientWidth < document.documentElement.clientHeight
    document.getElementById('{{product.id}}').src = 'http://www.placehold.it/500x500?text={{product.id}}'
  else
    document.getElementById('{{product.id}}').src = 'http://www.placehold.it/809x500?text={{product.id}}'
```

in my controllers.coffee, and obviously javascript will never execute that: what is the right way to use data binding in javascript so I can use this code?

```
a(ng-href='#!/products/{{product.id}}')
  img(alt='{{product.product}}', id='{{product.id}}')
```

Comment: this is completely the wrong way to approach this.  use `ng-if` in your HTML template instead of `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @Claies oh thank you, now that makes more sense. I'm sorry for asking dumb questions but I'm still learning and I don't know every directive.

Comment: keep this in mind while learning angular ...it is very rare you need to manipulate the dom yourself. Take a few minutes to walk through the various core directives in the api. It will be time well spent

Comment: @charlietfl it will be done, thank you!

Comment: @Claies why do I get only false with 
`img(alt='{{product.product}}', ng-src="{{document.documentElement.clientWidth < document.documentElement.clientHeight && 'http://www.placehold.it/500x500' || 'http://www.placehold.it/809x500'}}")` ?

Comment: errr I'm not sure?  that's not any code I recommended?  It doesn't look like it's right, though....

Comment: @Claies but with ng-if I can just hide and show, doesn't it? ng-src works in {{condition && true || false}}, what am I doin wrong?

Comment: that's not the right syntax.  I *suspect* what you want is `condition ? true : false`. (ternary operator).